# length of string is 54 although there is no input

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

i've been trying to combine 6 digits as one string but I check the length of the combinedPin, it's 54 although I haven't input anything yet

here's the piece of my code

```
combinedPin = "" + this.pinCode1 + this.pinCode2 + this.pinCode3 + this.pinCode4 + this.pinCode5 + this.pinCode6;
combinedPinInt = parseInt(combinedPin);
console.log("pincode: " + combinedPinInt + " length: " + combinedPin.length + " typeof: " + typeof combinedPin);
```

what is happening here? where did the 54 come from?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Are the pinCodes already strings? Are the possibly empty strings? Does the console.log give you more information, and would a console.log of each pinCode give you more information? Does changing to `parseInt(combinedPin, 10)` to enforce base 10 change anything (it shouldn't, but worth a try)?

Comment: console log the combinedPin and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here seems to be related to how JavaScript is interpreting the variables `this.pinCode1` through `this.pinCode6`. JavaScript might be converting undefined variables to "undefined" strings when you are trying to concatenate them. That would increase the length of your `combinedPin` string.

Here's a potential example of what could be happening:

```js
pinCode1 = undefined
pinCode2 = undefined
pinCode3 = undefined
pinCode4 = undefined
pinCode5 = undefined
pinCode6 = undefined

combinedPin = "" + this.pinCode1 + this.pinCode2 + this.pinCode3 + this.pinCode4 + this.pinCode5 + this.pinCode6;

console.log(combinedPin.length)  // Prints: 54
```

Each "`undefined`" string has 9 characters and you are concatenating 6 of them, which results in a total of 54 characters.

To solve this problem, you need to ensure that `pinCode1` through `pinCode6` are correctly defined and hold the values you expect before the concatenation operation.

If you could show more of the code, I might be able to help you with a potential fix.

It could also be something else, but it's quite coincidental that it logs exactly 54. That's why I suspect that all the values are undefined.

Comment: To verify my suspicion, you could try executing `console.log(combinedPinInt, typeof combinedPinInt)`. If my hypothesis is correct, it should log `NaN 'number'`.

Comment: yes, your hypothesis is right! and i believe I have solved it thanks to you too. i predefined each pincode = "0" (this is a string) and it is now showing length = 0 even when I haven't input anything. thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it helped you out :)